# Which jQuery function is there to hide an element by making it transparent?

Tags: jquery

Which jQuery function is there to hide an element by making it transparent instead of drawing it out (which is provided in [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide) jQuery functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$(selector).css('visibility', 'hidden');`

Comment: +1, and, please, take a moment to read the [mark-down editing/help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), to see how to format in-line code examples (among other things) :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other responses, if you want an animation, you can apply your own by using the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. Then you can animate the css-property you want (with some limitations):

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
    $('#bar').animate({opacity: 0}, 5000, function(){
        // #bar is gone!
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gncby/).